# How do I pick a good representation for a board game tactic for a genetic algorithm?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, data-representation

For my bachelor's thesis I want to write a genetic algorithm that learns to play the game of Stratego (if you don't know this game, it's probably safe to assume I said chess). I haven't ever before done actual AI projects, so it's an eye-opener to see how little I actually know of implementing things.

The thing I'm stuck with is coming up with a good representation for an actual strategy. I'm probably making some thinking error, but some problems I encounter:

- I don't assume you would have a representation containing a lot of
  transitions between board positions, since that would just be
  bruteforcing it, right?
- What could branches of a decision tree look
  like? Any representation I come up with don't have interchangeable
  branches... If I were to use a bit string, which is apparently also
  common, what would the bits represent?
- Do I assign scores to the distance between certain pieces? How would I represent that?

I think I ought to know these things after three+ years of study, so I feel pretty stupid - this must look likeI have no clue at all. Still, any help or tips on what to Google would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

I think, you could define a decision model and then try to optimize the parameters of that model. You can create multi-stage decision models also. I once did something similar for solving a dynamic dial-a-ride problem ([paper here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5258763)) by modeling it as a two stage linear decision problem. To give you an example, you could:

1. For each of your figures decide which one is to move next. Each figure is characterized by certain features derived from its position on the board, e.g. ability to make a score, danger, protecting x other figures, and so on. Each of these features can be combined (e.g. in a linear model, through a neural network, through a symbolic expression tree, a decision tree, ...) and give you a rank on which figure to act next with.
2. Acting with the figure you selected. Again there are a certain number of actions that can be taken, each has certain features. Again you can combine and rank them and one action will have the highest priority. This is the one you choose to perform.

The features you extract can be very simple or insanely complex, it's up to what you think will work best vs what takes how long to compute.

To evaluate and improve the quality of your decision model you can then simulate these decisions in several games against opponents and train the parameters of the model that combines these features to rank the moves (e.g. using a GA). This way you tune the model to win as many games as possible against the specified opponents. You can test the generality of that model by playing against opponents it has not seen before.

As Mathew Hall just said, you can use GP for this (if your model is a complex rule), but this is just one kind of model. In my case a linear combination of the weights did very well.

Btw, if you're interested we've also got a software on heuristic optimization which provides you with GA, GP and that stuff. It's called [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com). It's GPL and open source, but comes with a GUI (Windows). We've some Howto on how to evaluate the fitness function in an external program (data exchange using protocol buffers), so you can work on your simulation and your decision model and let the algorithms present in HeuristicLab optimize your parameters.

Comment: +1 for the approach of optimizing a set of parameters of a decision model.  This is the most straight-forward way of implementing a genetic approach to play a board game with a large number of states (as in stratego/chess).

Comment: This will probably the approach I am going to take. Unfortunately, my University is not subscribed to your publication, so I can't read your paper. Still, I think your comment is very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Vincent,

First, don't feel stupid.  You've been (I infer) studying basic computer science for three years; now you're applying those basic techniques to something pretty specialized-- a particular application (Stratego) in a narrow field (artificial intelligence.)

Second, make sure your advisor fully understands the rules of Stratego.  Stratego is played on a larger board, with more pieces (and more types of pieces) than chess.  This gives it a vastly larger space of legal positions, and a vastly larger space of legal moves.  It is also a game of hidden information, increasing the difficulty yet again.  Your advisor may want to limit the scope of the project, e.g., concentrate on a variant with full observation.  I don't know why you think this is simpler, except that the moves of the pieces are a little simpler.

Third, I think the right thing to do at first is to take a look at how games in general are handled in the field of AI.  Russell and Norvig, chapters 3 (for general background) and 5 (for two player games) are pretty accessible and well-written.  You'll see two basic ideas:  One, that you're basically performing a huge search in a tree looking for a win, and two, that for any non-trivial game, the trees are too large, so you search to a certain depth and then cop out with a "board evaluation function" and look for one of those.  I think your third bullet point is in this vein.

The board evaluation function is the magic, and probably a good candidate for using either a genetic algorithm, or a genetic program, either of which might be used in conjunction with a neural network.  The basic idea is that you are trying to design (or evolve, actually) a function that takes as input a board position, and outputs a single number.  Large numbers correspond to strong positions, and small numbers to weak positions.  There is a famous paper by Chellapilla and Fogel showing how to do this for a game of Checkers:

http://library.natural-selection.com/Library/1999/Evolving_NN_Checkers.pdf

I think that's a great paper, tying three great strands of AI together:  Adversarial search, genetic algorithms, and neural networks.  It should give you some inspiration about how to represent your board, how to think about board evaluations, etc.

Be warned, though, that what you're trying to do is substantially more complex than Chellapilla and Fogel's work.  That's okay-- it's 13 years later, after all, and you'll be at this for a while.  You're still going to have a problem representing the board, because the AI player has imperfect knowledge of its opponent's state; initially, nothing is known but positions, but eventually as pieces are eliminated in conflict, one can start using First Order Logic or related techniques to start narrowing down individual pieces, and possibly even probabilistic methods to infer information about the whole set.  (Some of these may be beyond the scope of an undergrad project.)

Answer (score 2):

The fact you are having problems coming up with a representation for an actual strategy is not that surprising. In fact I would argue that it is the most challenging part of what you are attempting. Unfortunately, I haven't heard of Stratego so being a bit lazy I am going to assume you said chess.

The trouble is that a chess strategy is rather a complex thing. You suggest in your answer containing lots of transitions between board positions in the GA, but a chess board has more possible positions than the number of atoms in the universe this is clearly not going to work very well. What you will likely need to do is encode in the GA a series of weights/parameters that are attached to something that takes in the board position and fires out a move, I believe this is what you are hinting at in your second suggestion.

Probably the simplest suggestion would be to use some sort of generic function approximation like a neural network; [Perceptrons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) or [Radial Basis Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network) are two possibilities. You can encode weights for the various nodes into the GA, although there are other fairly sound ways to train a neural network, see [Backpropagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation). You could perhaps encode the network structure instead/as well, this also has the advantage that I am pretty sure a fair amount of research has been done into developing neural networks with a genetic algorithm so you wouldn't be starting completely from scratch.

You still need to come up with how you are going to present the board to the neural network and interpret the result from it. Especially, with chess you would have to take note that a lot of moves will be illegal. It would be very beneficial if you could encode the board and interpret the result such that only legal moves are presented. I would suggest implementing the mechanics of the system and then playing around with different board representations to see what gives good results. A few ideas top of the head ideas to get you started could be, although I am not really convinced any of them are especially great ways to do this:

- A bit string with all 64 squares one after another with a number presenting what is present in each square. Most obvious, but probably a rather bad representation as a lot of work will be required to filter out illegal moves.
- A bit string with all 64 squares one after another with a number presenting what can move to each square. This has the advantage of embodying the covering concept of chess where you what to gain as much coverage of the board with your pieces as possible, but still has problems with illegal moves and dealing with friendly/enemy pieces.
- A bit string with all 32 pieces one after another with a number presenting the location of that piece in each square.

In general though I would suggest that chess is rather a complex game to start with, I think it will be rather hard to get something playing to standard which is noticeably better than random. I don't know if Stratego is any simpler, but I would strongly suggest you opt for a fairly simple game. This will let you focus on getting the mechanics of the implementation correct and the representation of the game state.

Anyway hope that is of some help to you.

**EDIT:** As a quick addition it is worth looking into how standard chess AI's work, I believe most use some sort of [Minimax system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax).

Comment: Stratego is indeed a bit simpler in the regard that it has fewer possible moves - it was at least simple enough that our mentor (not sure if that's the correct term) approved it. Since chess is well-known and as far as this question goes probably similar enough, I decided to go with that. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

When you say "tactic", do you mean you want the GA to give you a general algorithm to play the game (i.e. evolve an AI) or do you want the game to use a GA to search the space of possible moves to generate a move at each turn?

If you want to do the former, then look into using **Genetic programming** (GP). You could try to use it to produce the best AI you can for a fixed tree size. [JGAP](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/) already comes with support for GP as well. See the [JGAP Robocode example](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/doc/robocode/robocode.html) for an instance of this. This approach does mean you need a domain specific language for a Stratego AI, so you'll need to think carefully how you expose the board and pieces to it.

Using GP means your fitness function can just be how well the AI does at a fixed number of pre-programmed games, but that requires a good AI player to start with (or a very patient human).

Comment: I want to evolve it in advance so it can play the game at a reasonable level later, so the former. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

@DonAndre's answer is absolutely correct for movement. In general, problems involving state-based decisions are hard to model with GAs, requiring some form of GP (either explicit or, as @DonAndre suggested, trees that are essentially declarative programs).

A general Stratego player seems to me quite challenging, but if you have a reasonable Stratego playing program, "Setting up your Stratego board" would be an excellent GA problem. The initial positions of your pieces would be the phenotype and the outcome of the external Stratego-playing code would be the fitness. It is intuitively likely that random setups would be disadvantaged versus setups that have a few "good ideas" and that small "good ideas" could be combined into fitter-and-fitter setups.

...

On the general problem of what a decision tree, even trying to come up with a simple example, I kept finding it hard to come up with a small enough example, but maybe in the case where you are evaluation whether to attack a same-ranked piece (which, IIRC destroys both you and the other piece?):

```
double locationNeed = aVeryComplexDecisionTree();
if(thatRank == thisRank){
   double sacrificeWillingness = SACRIFICE_GENETIC_BASE; //Assume range 0.0 - 1.0
   double sacrificeNeed = anotherComplexTree(); //0.0 - 1.0
   double sacrificeInContext = sacrificeNeed * SACRIFICE_NEED_GENETIC_DISCOUNT; //0.0 - 1.0  
   if(sacrificeInContext > sacrificeNeed){
      ...OK, this piece is "willing" to sacrifice itself
```

One way or the other, the basic idea is that you'd *still* have a lot of coding of Stratego-play, you'd just be seeking places where you could insert parameters that would change the outcome. Here I had the idea of a "base" disposition to sacrifice itself (presumably higher in common pieces) and a "discount" genetically-determined parameter that would weight whether the piece would "accept or reject" the need for a sacrifice.